# Insert arbitrary number of rows into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which is doing a merge and updating several tables with the new IDs etc.

What I am trying to do is record the items and their related items into a table just in case it needs to be reverted. I have the data ready to be transferred sitting in multiple temporary tables in the stored procedure, I have a blank table ready to receive the data I just don't know how I'm going to insert it in there.....

The number of items maybe 1 or maybe 10.....anyone any ideas on how I might achieve this?

Comment: please explain using some examples  not in terms of words

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

OK for some reason this slipped my mind, im actually doing it in the same SP :)

```
INSERT INTO [tblMyTable]([Field1])
    SELECT [DataField]
    FROM [tblDataTable]
```

very easy :)